# Linker not working on solc v0.4.23

Tags: solc

I can't seem to make the `linker.linkBytecode()` method to work...

Here's how I'm using it:

```
const linkedBytecode = linker.linkBytecode(mainContract.bytecode, {
        'UserLib': userLibContract.options.address
 });
```

If I try to `console.log(linkedBytecode)` it outputs the bytecode with placeholders that should've been replaced by the linker!

I noticed that the compiled bytecode of my `mainContract` outputs something like `...5173__IssueLib.sol:IssueLib_________________916....` whereas on the official documentation it says that it should output something like `...5173__IssueLib_______________916....`

What Am I missing here?

Thanks in advance! :)